# What’s happening to my Jacaranda

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, diseases, leaves

Recently my jacaranda leaf are starting to appear lazy and heavy. I’ve notice some deposit on the leaf, what is it? Should I be worried?

[image]

[image]

Comment: TOO LATE... it died slowly in a painful death